# Applying for Netherlands RNI abroad in english

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands, residency

I am moving to the Netherlands and I would like to apply for an RNI (Registratie Niet Ingezetenen) in English online. Is this possible? If not where is the easiest place to book an appointment so that once I am there I can do it ASAP.

I have tried to email the address on [this page](https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/local/official-matters/amsterdam-city-districts/stadsdeel-centrum) but I have not received a reply in a week.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain you should be applying for this? It appears rather that the procedure would be to move to the Netherlands first and then register as a resident (*niet-ingezetenen* roughly means *nonresident*).

Comment: This would be the quickest way to get my BSN which I need ASAP to open a bank account so I can get accommodation... I cant see a faster way of doing this, do you have any suggestions

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any better way of doing it, but there must be another way of doing it since the RNI is a relatively recent development (in the last few years) and expatriates have been moving to the Netherlands for decades.  Your plan seems to be workable only if you in fact qualify to register as a nonresident; that seems to be intended for people who are already paying taxes or receiving a pension or the like; you've given no indication that you already have a similar relationship with the Dutch authorities.

Comment: Note that if you're going to be working for a Dutch company, they can apply on your behalf (although you still have to show up at some point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply for it online, it's necessary to show up in person. Since you are moving to the Netherlands, the usual way to get a BSN would be to register with your new municipality of residence as soon as you settle in the country (it's mandatory anyway). You will automatically get a BSN (and a proof of registration, which you would also need for some formalities).

If you really feel you need to register as a non-resident before moving, you still need to show up at [one of 19 municipalities](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/persoonsgegevens/vraag-en-antwoord/wat-is-de-registratie-niet-ingezetenen-rni) including Amsterdam. The page you found suggest that you don't need an appointment for that.

The information available in Dutch is understandably more comprehensive but you will almost certainly find someone who speaks English and is willing to help you in that language at the municipality.